# shorte.st new api convert to php curl

Tags: api, curl

shorte.st is a url shorten service.
recently they changed the api as following:
curl commandline

```
curl H "public-api-token: fakekey" -X -d "urlToShorten=google.com" PUT http://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url
```

response:

```
 {"status":"ok","shortenedUrl":"http:\/\/sh.st\/XXXX"}
```

How to change it into php curl version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function shst($url){
$apiurl="https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('public-api-token: fakekey','X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "urlToShorten=".$url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
$obj = json_decode($data);
$ret=$obj->{'shortenedUrl'};

return $ret;
}
```

The sample they provided used the wrong url. should be https not http

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
function shst($url){
    $key="";//your key
    $curl_url = "https://api.shorte.st/s/".$key."/".$url;
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    $array = json_decode($result);
    $shortest = $array->shortenedUrl;
    return $shortest;
}
```